# MongoDB - Update subdocuments using javascript

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, subdocument

The documents in my `apps` collection each contain a subcollection of users. Now I need to update a single user per app given a set of `_id`s for the `apps` collection using javascript. I cannot use a regular call to `update()` for this, as the data inserted will be encrypted using a public key stored within the app document. Therefore the data written into the user-subdocument is dependant on the app-document it is contained in. Pseudo-code of what I need to do:

```
foreach app in apps:
    app.users.$.encryptedData = encrypt(data, app.publicKey)
```

One way to do it would be to find all the apps and then use `forEach()` to update every single app. However, this seems to be quite inefficient to me, as all the app-documents would have to be found twice in the database, one time to gather all of them and then another time to update every single document. There has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: No, there is no other way since your data is encrypted clientside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that no, you can not update a document in mongoDB with a value from that document.

Have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/5293110
for ideas other that doing the iteration yourself.